# How to receive Push notification message in iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, apple-push-notifications

I created .pem file following steps

1. Log-in to the iPhone Developer Program Portal.
2. Choose App IDs from the menu on the right.
3. Create an App ID without a wildcard.
4. Click the Configure link next to this App ID and then click on the button to start the wizard to generate a new Development Push SSL Certificate.
5. Download this certificate and double click on aps_developer_identity.cer to import it into your Keychain
6. Launch Keychain Assistant and click on My Certificates on the left
7. Expand Apple IOS Development Push Services and select Apple IOS Development Push Services AND my private key
8. Right-click and choose "Export 2 elements..." and save as cert.p12.
9. Open Terminal and change directory to location used to save cert.p12 and convert the PKCS12 certificate bundle into PEM format using this command
   openssl pkcs12 -in cert.p12 -out cert.pem -nodes -clcerts
   10.Now i use this PEM file as my certificate in ApnsPHP!

while i use the url in the browser it display; {"aps":{"alert":"hi","badge":1,"sound":"beep.wav"}}

I am using this code to receive notification in iphone app

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 

    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\nRegistering for push notifications...\n\n\n\n");    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | 
      UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    NSString *token = [[devToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n\n device token===%@\n\n\n\n",token);
    //DeviceRegisterer *registrar = [[DeviceRegisterer alloc] init];
    //[registrar registerDeviceWithToken:token];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    NSLog(@"failed to regiser %@", err);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"notification options %@", userInfo);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Super" message:@"welcome" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    for (id key in userInfo) {


        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your title here!" message:@"this gets covered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        UITextField *myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 45.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
        [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        myTextField.text = [userInfo objectForKey:key];
        [myAlertView addSubview:myTextField];
        [myAlertView show];
        [myAlertView release];

    }    

}
```

But am not able to receive the notification message.
Please help to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance,
Senthilkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. Problem in the php  .pem file attactment . thanks for gave idea.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using a server to send the message. The pem key is meant to be used by a server to send the message. I think that you cannot use your iphone app to send directly a push message.
If your server is using php try to find in this site the code to delivery the notifications.
Note: On my server the ApnsPHP code do not work at all, I used a simple php script found in stackOverflow (sorry do not remember the link) to manage it and works.

Comment: <?php
$deviceToken = '0f744707bebcf74f9b7c25d48e3358945f6aa01da5ddb387462c7eaf61bbad78';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';
// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'My first push notification!';
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
 $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

Comment: if (!$fp)
 exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
 'alert' => $message,
 'sound' => 'default'
 );
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
 echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
 echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

fclose($fp);